# Drupal 7 fields - only editable by specific roles - how?

Tags: php, drupal, permissions, drupal-7, field

I have some fields that my users cannot be allowed to edit - however, certain roles would need permission to do so. There are also other fields that the user may edit.

How would I do this? I tried looking in roles.
I did see this question: [Drupal, user profiles: adding fields *only* editable by administrators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3268161/drupal-user-profiles-adding-fields-only-editable-by-administrators)

but couldnt figure out how to make sure that the fields are never editable by regular users, and also how to make sure only specific roles can edit.
I'm fairly good with php, but i can't seem to find my way around on the drupal site.

/Anders

Answer (score 6, accepted):

have you tried using [Field Permissions](http://drupal.org/project/field_permissions) module.

Comment: that's good. Now why don't you thank me the way it is actually supposed to be. By actually selecting my answer as correct :)

Comment: I was going to - but i had to wait for some reason. :)